# BarChart doesn't show all categories

Tags: java, javafx

```
XYChart.Series set=new XYChart.Series<>();
set.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("#Purchases",arrint.get(0)));
set.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("#Searches",arrint.get(1)));
mybar.getData().addAll(set);
```

Im using javafx with BarChart, and i see very well the graphs. the problem is that i cant see the string 'purchases', while searches is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me. You might need to update your version of Java JDK, and JRE.

```
public class JavaFXApplication9 extends Application {

    final static String itemA = "#Purchases";//"A";
    final static String itemB = "#Searches";//"B";
    final static String itemC = "F";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String, Number> bc = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Value");
        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
        yAxis.setLabel("Item");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(itemA, 2));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(itemB, 20));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(itemC, 10));

//        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
//        series2.setName("2004");
//        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(50, itemA));
//        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(41, itemB));
//        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(45, itemC));
//
//        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
//        series3.setName("2005");
//        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(45, itemA));
//        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(44, itemB));
//        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, itemC));

//        Timeline tl = new Timeline();
//        tl.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), 
//            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
//                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
//                for (XYChart.Series<Number, String> series : bc.getData()) {
//                    for (XYChart.Data<Number, String> data : series.getData()) {
//                        data.setXValue(Math.random() * 100);
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//        }));
//        tl.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
//        tl.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);
        bc.getData().add(series1);//.addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: In that case, please appreciate the time invested by the answerer at least by accepting the answer.